# GraphQL how to check if a field exists

Tags: graphql, datocms

How can I make a query and check if a field exists in `graphql`?

I have e.g. tried with the following query:

```
query MyQuery($slug: String!) {
   page(filter: {slug: {eq: $slug}}) {
     ... on PageRecord {
       qaBlock {
         items {
           header
           content
         }
       title
      }
    }
  }
}
```

so my issue is, that as soon I hit a page, where the QA block doesn't exist, the page breaks and I get an error `Field 'qaBlock' doesn't exist on type 'PageRecord'`

is there a way to solve this? My desired output would be something like:

```
{
  qaBlock: null /// or just []
}
```

Comment: Not really possible afaik. You could just trap the error and go from there. Alternatively you could introspect the schema and deduce the absence or presence of fields from that.